# JQuery validation does not update error element for a next error if "errorPlacement" 's been modified.

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

work ok:

```
errorPlacement:
                function(error, element) {
                    error.appendTo( element.parent());                         
                },
```

fail:

```
errorPlacement:
                function(error, element) {
                    error.appendTo( element.parent()); 
                    $(element).prop("title", error.text());
                },
```

With second snippet I see only the first error. For example I have input that is "required" and "number" - submit form - **required error** is shown - fill in *letters* - **required error** is shown.

Dubbuging the errorPlacement I can see that `error` DOM is always the same.

Thanks in advance for any help!

PS: **Goal**: I want to show errors as tool-tips.

Comment: So, you want to show errors in tooltips, fine (even if it is not a very good idea from a UI standpoint IMHO - validation messages should be as visible as possible, since you want the user to realize his mistake in order for him to correct it, hover tooltips don't do this well). You're setting the `title` property of the invalid element to achieve that. But are you reverting this action in a [success](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) callback if/when the element becomes valid again?

Comment: Together with tool-tip I use styles to show user their mistakes. Can you tell what should I do inside success? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

this Plugin may help you: http://jquery.dop-trois.org/walidate/

There it's possible to define a lot of callback-functions.
For example: if sth is invalid or valid ..

So you can develop your own tooltips ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do

`element.attr("title", error.text());`

instead of

`$(element).prop("title", error.text());`

element is already a jquery element in the jquery validate plugin: http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate